# Is Swipe method supported in Android Appium version 1.3.4?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I have tried implementing the swipe method for android devices, but this method is not working in Appium 1.3.4.
Below is the code I have written:

```
public void swipe() {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    HashMap < String, Double > swipeObject = new HashMap < String, Double > ();
    swipeObject.put("startX", 0.95);
    swipeObject.put("startY", 0.5);
    swipeObject.put("endX", 0.05);
    swipeObject.put("endY", 0.5);
    swipeObject.put("duration", 1.0);
    js.executeScript("emulator: swipe", swipeObject);
}
```

And call the swipe() in required place in that same class.
It throws error message like this:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please
>   help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did
>   not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 7
>   milliseconds

Please anyone help me on this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should migrate action methods to TouchAction class, in case of swipe, try this:

```
def swipe(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y)
    Appium::TouchAction.new.press(x: start_x, y: start_y).wait(1000).move_to(x:end_x, y:end_y).wait(500).release(x: end_x, y: end_y).perform
end
```

Check API in here: http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html

Instead of coordinated you can also pass elements.

Comment: TouchAction looks good, also check the example in this issue: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4268